# Saving image force close application in android

Tags: android, image, storage

I'm implementing a save function to save a custom drawable view as an image. The problem is that the JPG image is created but it does not contain anything and finally the program "stops working unfortunately " Can anyone help me please here is my code;

```
    Bitmap b = drawView.getDrawingCache();
    File storage =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(storage,spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()+".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos;
              try {
               fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
               b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95,fos);
               fos.flush();
               fos.close();
              } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                drawView.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Which exception it throws? Please post your logcat for more clarification.

Comment: that's the problem, on emulator the application done create any file at all it creates it only on my tablet, On the emulator there are no errors and the apps does not crash but nothing is saved

Comment: 10-08 04:24:12.225: I/dalvikvm-heap(1244): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.155MB for 3160016-byte allocation

10-08 04:24:12.345: D/dalvikvm(1244): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 18% free 12305K/14956K, paused 73ms+10ms, total 117ms

10-08 04:24:12.345: D/dalvikvm(1244): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
10-08 04:24:12.705: I/Choreographer(1244): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

10-08 04:27:05.326: D/dalvikvm(1244): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6177K, 31% free 6134K/8784K, paused 116ms, total 125ms

Comment: 10-08 04:27:05.406: I/dalvikvm-heap(1244): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.140MB for 3160016-byte allocation
10-08 04:27:05.546: D/dalvikvm(1244): GC_CONCURRENT freed 368K, 26% free 8852K/11872K, paused 47ms+5ms, total 144ms
10-08 04:27:05.546: D/dalvikvm(1244): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 97ms

Comment: sorry for the presentation im not able to put it conveniently

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
  private void SaveIamge(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

      String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
      File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
      myDir.mkdirs();
      Random generator = new Random();
      int n = 10000;
      n = generator.nextInt(n);
      String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
      File file = new File (myDir, fname);
      if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
        try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

and add this in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I have try the codes the following codes, it store the images without crashing the app but still the images are empty, I mean 0 Kb.

Comment: how to i do this please?